# .ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when navigate back to the fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I created group of chips, and I pick element from array by which chip is clicked:

```
  myChips.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
            if (checkedId != -1) {
                chipFromArray = foodArray[checkedId - 1]
            } else {
                chipFromArray = foodArray[0]
            }
```

It works great when I stay inside the fragment, but when I navigate to other fragment, and then navigate back and choose a chip i'm getting this exeption:

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

Logs for picking the second chip:

checked id -> 2

checked id after navigate,
 getting back and picking the second chip again -> 9

Crash:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.newsapp, PID: 9026
>       java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=8

Array init:         `val foodArray= resources.getStringArray(R.array.food_array)`[array size like chip group size. static.]

Comment: Can you add crash logs and also provide foodArray initialization?

Comment: checkedId is id of chip not index.

Comment: I updated the question.   So why the id changed every time I navigate? and how can I get the actual postion?

Comment: Chip chip = group.findViewById(checkedId);  and chipFromArray = chip.getText()

Answer (score 0):

As  Kasım Özdemir suggested in the comments, I can do like this:

```
val chip = group.findViewById<Chip>(checkedId)
val chipText = chip.text
```